# Dynamic synchronous require targeting itself or current working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require

I'm writing a NodeJS package and part of the function does a dynamic synchronous require in the following manner:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

function main(params) {
  const data = require(params.json);
  // do things with data
}
```

My expectation for the `params.json` is that the person using this project could either provide a path to a library within my project, which is shipped along with it OR point it at their own in their project.

```js
import main from 'my-project';
import json from 'my-project/lib/some.json';

function main({ json }); // should work
```

```js
import main from 'my-project';
import json from './path/to/some.json';

function main({ json }); // should also work
```

However, I can only get one of these to work at a time so far. I can either do a straight `require` as shown above (which looks only within `my-project`) OR do `require(path.resolve(params.json))` which looks at the `cwd` and needs an ugly `node_modules` path back to my project to work.

[My understanding](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) of the resolver was that it would look for `my-project` in `node_modules` first before then considering it a path within the project.

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a core module, and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then Node.js starts at the directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location.

As an example:

```js
const React = require('react'); // finds React in `node_modules/react`
const localproject = require('./stuff'); // finds some local JS stuff
```

I am reading that the `"main"` key in the `package.json` might also have an effect here, so I'll provide the relevant parts as well:

```json
  "main": "./dist/index.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs"
    },
    "./lib/*": "./lib/*"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "lib"
  ],
```

The function is exported out of both `index.cjs` and `index.mjs` to cover CJS and ESM. The library of `.json` I'm looking to expose is found at `/lib`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this the issue is in the way youre using require with the dynamic JSON file path. When using the dynamic JSON file path, you want to prioritize loading the JSON from the local project if it exists, and fall back to loading it from the package if it doesn't.

You can fix this with using `require.resolve` with a try-catch block

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

function main(params) {
  let data;

  try {
    // Attempt to load the JSON from the local project
    const localJsonPath = require.resolve(params.json);
    data = require(localJsonPath);
  } catch (error) {
    // If the local JSON file doesn't exist, fall back to loading from the package
    data = require(params.json);
  }

  // do things with data
}
```

Comment: I've thought about doing that, but I was under the impression (from the docs I linked) that this would happen with the normal require already.

Comment: "If the module identifier passed to require() is not a core module, and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then Node.js starts at the directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location"